# how to execute more than thousand requests in parallel by axios using node.js

Tags: node.js, axios, es6-promise, cheerio

***When I try to make axios.get request(url) for a small number of URLs it works successfully but when the number of URLs is large I get an errors from axios ( socket hang up - Client network socket disconnected before  secure TLS connection was established - read ECONNRESET - connect ETIMEDOUT).***

my code

I try to loop through this array

```
const links =  [
      {
        title: 'title two',
        newsLink: 'https://al-omana.net/details.php?id=158277',
        imageLink: 'https://al-omana.net/media/imgs/news/25-09-2021-04-18-26.jpeg',
        category: 'news',
        rssId: 321,
        selector: '.story_text p'
      },
      {
        title: 'title one',
        newsLink: 'https://al-omana.net/details.php?id=158277',
        imageLink: 'https://al-omana.net/media/imgs/news/25-09-2021-04-18-26.jpeg',
        category: 'news',
        rssId: 123,
        selector: '.story_text p'
      },
      ... 1415 more items
    ]
```

and I try to extract the content by this function

```
async function scrapeContent(item) {
  try {
    let content = "";
    const { data } = await axios.get(item.newsLink);

    const $ = cheerio.load(data);
    const listItems = $(item.selector);

    listItems.each((_, item) => {
      content += $(item).text();
    });

    return {
      ...item,
      content: content.replace(/[\r\n\"\t]+/gm, "")
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log({ in: "scrapeContent", message: error.message });
  }
}
```

and this my execute function

```
async function scraper(links) {
    try {
        const promises = links.map(scrapeContent); // this loop axios requests
        const newsContent = await Promise.all(promises);

        console.log(newsContent);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log({ in: "scraper", message: error.message });
    }

scraper(links);
```

Please help me

Comment: Are you sending thousands of requests to the same server in a short period of time? Most security systems will block this.

Comment: @jabaa No, not for the same server, but for different servers

Comment: In your example the first two links are for the same domain.

Comment: @jabaa Yes, not more than three or four, five as a maximum